# ManifoldCF ERROR JCIFS connector, crash agents

Tags: jcifs, manifoldcf

I used ManifoldCF 2.7 with multiprocess-zk and after 10 minutes my 2 agents crash. ERROR :

```
jcifs.smb.SmbException
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:631)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:643)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:660)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)
 WARN 2017-06-14 09:28:00,384 (Worker thread '12') - JCIFS: Possibly transient exception detected on attempt 2 while getting file security: null
jcifs.smb.SmbException
jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:631)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:643)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)

    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:660)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.queryPath(SmbFile.java:1366)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.exists(SmbFile.java:1420)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.isDirectory(SmbFile.java:1493)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getSecurity(SmbFile.java:2895)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecurity(SharedDriveConnector.java:2395)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.getFileSecuritySet(SharedDriveConnector.java:1195)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.connectors.sharedrive.SharedDriveConnector.processDocuments(SharedDriveConnector.java:639)
    at org.apache.manifoldcf.crawler.system.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:399)
```

It is the multiprocess-zk-example and I haved 2 agents started.

If you need more details, I am available.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Up
Help please.....

Comment: Up Help please.....